# I have two audio files of same song one is from vinyl and other is from CD source, I want to compare those and technically see the difference between

Tags: sound-design, audio, sound-effects, music, sound-effects-recording

**Music comparison** for getting vinyl effect in CD recording conversation from CD rip to vinyl rip

Comment: Reading between the lines, you want to make a CD rip sound like vinyl… why?

Comment: What is your question? You can use all sorts of frequency analysis tools to highlight the differences in dynamic range, frequency range, eq etc if that is what you want to know. Please edit your post to let us know what your question is.

Comment: I don't know why vinyl Rip is comfortable to me. I have studied that CD is technically far superior than vinyl in all technical aspects, but vinyl Rip sounds very good. Is there any training tool if I train to identify CD and Vinyl than same will helpe me to convert. The comparison should be with almost musical attributes frequency, amplitude, dynamics, loudness etc. I need to technically differ them, by deeplearning or training a model. It least a model which will after Deep learning will identify the difference and the same will help to convert. Like Music retrieval I confused where to start

Answer (score 2):

*This answer may contain <strike>nuts</strike> cynicism.*

To make a CD rip sound like the average consumer vinyl rip, you need to do the following…

- Apply a gentle roll-off of frequencies above 4KHz, not too much, just enough that there's nothing much left above about 12k.
- Hard roll off anything below 45Hz.
- Add gentle tube or tape saturation.
- Optional. De-tune [by simply speeding or slowing] to within approximately 50 cents of original pitch. Do this randomly per rip.
- Optional, for older records… compress using a very slow attack & release, to make it 'as loud' as a new record.
- Use something like Steinberg's 'Vinyl' VST plugin to add some gentle pops, clicks & rumble. This can also add considerably more distortion & frequency squeezing if you want that authentic 78 sound.
- Transcode to FLAC [or round robin to low bitrate mp3, then back to FLAC 48kHz] & sit back, happy you made it 'better' than the CD.

Comment: So cynical:-) I have to say I far prefer the sound of a well mastered old school LP to modern mastering. I don't think it's better, I just like what I grew up with, probably

Comment: @RoryAlsop - for sure;))  I have some fabulous old vinyl albums, & some early CDs rushed off the EQ masters which were downright bloody awful, but my point really is that the average vinyl ripper's gear is simply not up to the task, & once ripped tends to go through some kind of voodoo 'upscaling' process before being shared on usenet/torrent to fool people into thinking it's better than it is. Most times you'd get a better sounding file off iTunes, which at least these days come off the 24-bit masters.